# Dynamically create table after INSERT to another table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.2

I have a table:

```
create table monthly_tran (id int,somedata text);
```

A row will add to this table **only** once in every month of a year.
After inserting a row to this table, I need to create a **new** table:

```
create table monthly_proc_X(id int,tranid int,somedata text);
```

*`X`* in *`monthly_proc_X`* should be the `id` of the newly inserted row in table `monthly_tran`.
For example If `(9,'some values')` is inserted, a table `monthly_proc_9` should get created.

***Note :  PostgreSQL 9.2***

Comment: Pity you did not provide your Postgres version, that's a dealbreaker for possible upvotes.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a trigger like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynTable() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
execute 'create table monthly_proc_'||new.id||'(id int,tranid int,somedata text)';
return new;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and assign to `monthly_tran`

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_create_table AFTER INSERT ON monthly_tran
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE dynTable();
```

The trigger `dynTable()` will create table dynamically when a new row is inserted to `monthly_tran`